# How can I perform a comparison of poisson and linear modelling using one dataset?

Tags: regression, poisson-regression, continuous-data, discrete-data

my y is average length of stay in months however the number of months in dataset is up to 60 so I can treat it as continuous but my main objective is to identify when can i determine it's better to treat is discrete or when is better to treat it as continuous. Thank you

Comment: You can compare the models using [AIC](http://stanfordphd.com/AIC.html), [BIC](http://stanfordphd.com/BIC.html) or another well-established model selection criterion.

Comment: Length of stay where?  Most LOS data are very skewed. And they are often censored.